# String manipulation performance and speed

Tags: c#, string, optimization, richtextbox

Below are three methods I have written for my `RichTextBox` derived class, which is a syntax highlighter. There is a shared copy, `lcpy_strLine`, of the current line of the richtextbox in all upper case. What these methods do is;

- **ColorInsideTwoChars** colors the characters between the two specified characters the specified color. Ex. `ColorInsideTwoChar("(", ")", Color.Green)` would color all the characters between two parenthesis green for all sets of parenthesis in the current line
- **ColorTilNoNumFromChar** colors, from the specified character, all of the characters that are numbers, Ex. `ColorTilNoNumFromChar("G", Color.Red)` would color all of the numbers after a G is encountered, red (this includes the G)
- **ColorCharIfNotFollowedByLetter** colors the specified character if it is not followed by a letter. Ex. `ColorCharIfNotFollowedByLetter("x", Color.Orange)` would color all the X's orange that are not followed by a letter

My question is, is there a faster way to do these methods. They look ugly and I think that there are definitely simpler and more aesthetic ways of doing these methods. Any suggestions? I ask because these methods are ran on each line of few thousand line files and are pretty slow. I need to speed them up. I could try and rewrite each of them a different way a few times, or I could have a few smarties try and head me in the right direction.

```
    private void ColorInsideTwoChars(String car1, String car2, Color clr)
    {
        int indx1 = 0;
        int indx2 = 0;
        while ((indx1 = lcpy_strLine.IndexOf(car1, indx1)) != -1
                && (indx2 = lcpy_strLine.IndexOf(car2, indx2)) != -1
                && indx1 < indx2)
        {
            SelectionStart = m_nLineStart + indx1;
            SelectionLength = (indx2 - indx1) + 1;
            SelectionColor = clr;
            indx1 = ++indx2;
        }
    }
    private void ColorTilNoNumFromChar(String car, Color clr)
    {
        int indx1 = 0;
        while ((indx1 = lcpy_strLine.IndexOf(car, indx1)) != -1)
        {
            int j = 0;
            for (j = indx1 + 1; j < m_nLineLength; j++)
            {
                if (!Char.IsDigit(lcpy_strLine[j]))
                    break;
            }
            SelectionStart = m_nLineStart + indx1;
            SelectionLength = j - indx1;
            SelectionColor = clr;
            indx1 = j;
        }
    }
    private void ColorCharIfNotFollowedByLetter(String car, Color clr)
    {
        int indx1 = 0;
        while ((indx1 = lcpy_strLine.IndexOf(car, indx1)) != -1 &&
            indx1 + 1 < m_nLineLength)
        {
            SelectionStart = m_nLineStart + indx1;
            SelectionLength = 1;
            if (!Char.IsLetter(lcpy_strLine[lcpy_strLine.IndexOf(car) + 1]))
                SelectionColor = clr;
            else
                SelectionColor = Color.Black;
            ++indx1;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried to use [Find](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3134f2f7) method of RichTextBox control? If no create methods and compare how much time takes to use different methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As for `ColorInsideTwoChar()`, note that you'll color what's in between parentheses even if they are nested, resulting in doing it more that once. What if parentheses (or these chars in general) aren't matched properly? Maybe find opening char, then mathing it closing char and color everything in between? Then start searching from position at which you had closing char, and look for the next opening one.. Also, I would call this only on line change, don't know what's your idea ;) And maybe only on visible part of RichBox first, and then color the rest in the background?

```
for (j = indx1 + 1; j < m_nLineLength; j++)
        {
            if (!Char.IsDigit(lcpy_strLine[j]))
                break;
        }
```

i would swap for

```
while (Char.IsDigit(lcpy_strLine[++j])) ;
```

although it's probably more or less the same...

But I think you should wait for some more professional answer, there's probably some more elegant way to do this.

Also, maybe finding *all* occurences of wanted chars at the beginning of methods, and putting them into an array, would be faster than looking them up again and again?

It might be also faster to do that for larger chunks of file than single lines...

Comment: I did try to color only the visiblelines, but it is still very very slow for large files. Almost impossible to scroll. So I have the user look at two text boxes in the beginning, top has colored text from the viewable area in the bottom. when the user clicks a button it starts a backgroundworker that starts coloring the text while the user can still look at the begging form, waiting for a colored text box to finish. I guess I need to see a big difference in any of these to see any real difference in performance. (takes 24mins for a 21208 line file to color)

Answer (score 0):

1] `ColorInsideTwoChars`
`ColorInsideTwoChars` colors the characters between the two specified characters the specified color. Ex. `ColorInsideTwoChar("(", ")", Color.Green)` would color all the characters between two parenthesis green for all sets of parenthesis in the current line

The bad thing about this function is `IndexOf` functions. Your performance will be O(n^2) if not worse. What you essentially should do, is:

Read line only once, and store all positions of braces into a new list. Like this:

```
var leftList = new List<int>();
var rightList = new List<int>();
for(var i = 0; i < str.Length; i++)
{
   if(str[i] == car1) leftList.Add(i);
   if(str[i] == car2) rightList.Add(i);
}

if(leftList.Length != rightList.Length) { /*possible error or no?!*/ }
//now start going like this:
int index1 = leftList.Length - 1;
int index2 = 0;
while(index1 >= 0 && index2 < rightList.Length)
{
  //do your coloring here.
  index1--;
  index2++;
}
```

This will be far faster than your current one. Though you will be trading a little memory, but it's okay. I suggest you to make those Lists as a variables of a class not a method. Also make sure they generally are big enough by default so no allocating will happen. And on next iteration, use `Clear()`.

2] `ColorTilNoNumFromChar` colors, from the specified character, all of the characters that are numbers, Ex. `ColorTilNoNumFromChar("G", Color.Red)` would color all of the numbers after a G is encountered, red (this includes the G)

I would not write it like this, but more a long this:

```
for(var i = 0; i < str.Length; i++)
{
   if(str[i] == "G")
   {
      int selectionStart = i + 1;
      int selectionLength = -1;
      for(var k = i + 1; k < str.Length; k++)
      {
         if(IsDigit(str[i]))
         {
            if(selectionLength == -1) selectionLength = 0;
            selectionLength++;
         } else break;
      }
      //look if selectionLength is not -1
      i = k;//advance.
   }
}
```

As of your last one, you also have there `IndexOf` which could be eliminated thus yielding more performance.

And if you are running those methods separately(each by each), then it's a nono. You should do everything at once(will be harder, but far faster).

Comment: How would I do them all at once?.. And thanks for the answer, this will help!

Comment: Actually I think your second method is fine. But for first one you might consider my one. 
And third one: 
if (!Char.IsLetter(lcpy_strLine[lcpy_strLine.IndexOf(car) + 1]))
I think this is a little incorrect. You want to throw in second parameter for indexOf too ;). 
I agree though, for best solution, you:
color only visible lines + 40 lines that are not visible, but are close to the visible lines. So it would appear as smooth. You do coloring on background, it should be smooth, no?

Comment: Coloring on background? And I have been/was having a difficult time only coloring a few lines that are shown, I could not get anything right.. So many out of bounds exceptions because of stupid base cases..